# How to compare email id in angularjs form submit

Tags: angularjs, validation, compare, email-validation

I want to compare email ids.

When I enter email id in repeat email input field then validation to take place

```
<form name ="myForm">
    Email:<input name="emailid" type="email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true"/>

    Repeat Email:<input type="email" name="emailRepeat" ng-model="email2" ng-required="true" ng-match="user.email">
    <span ng-show="myForm.emailRepeat.$error.match">Emails have to match!</span><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> or  <input type="button" ng-click="cancelUserAdd()" value ="Cancel"/>.
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inbuilt in angular to do so, but there are libraries that can get you started.

Check

https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-input-match

or the angular-ui utility belt

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Or you need to write your own validator.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Email:<input type="email" name="email1" ng-model="emailReg">
Repeat Email:<input type="email" name="email2" ng-model="emailReg2" ng-match="emailReg"></p>

<span data-ng-show="myForm.emailReg2.$error.match">Emails have to match!</span>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> or  <input type="button" ng-click="cancelUserAdd()" value ="Cancel"/>
```